# how to pass a parameter to cy.xpath

Tags: xpath, cypress

Pretty new to cypress as well as this forum.

I am trying to find a way to pass a value to cy.xpath during runtime but lost how to do it in cypress.
I am passing a randomized project title 'ProjectTitle' each time as a text to a field as below:

```js
cy.get('#project-title').type(ProjectTitle)
```

for eg at runtime the value for project title is generated as 'SampleProject 1224'

at a later point of time i want to verify if the title value i passed above is displayed.

this is the xpath i want to verify:

```js
cy.xpath("//div[@class='tm__owner-project-card-meta']/h3[text()='SampleProject 1224']")
.should('be.visible')
```

I do not want to hardcode the value for 'text()' as it changes each time based on the random title generated during runtime.

How do I pass the 'ProjectTitle' const to the text() in my xpath.

I tried something like this

```js
cy.xpath("//div[@class='tm__owner-project-card-meta']/h3[text()='${ProjectTitle}']")
.should('be.visible')
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [string template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax, but it requires the outer quotes to be backticks,

> Template literals are literals delimited with **backtick (`) characters** ...

something like the line below should work in this situation.

```js
cy.xpath(`//div[@class='tm__owner-project-card-meta']/h3[text()='${ProjectTitle}']`)
.should('be.visible')
```